# python assert total_area < 500 test

Tags: python, testing, polygon, geojson, assert

Im trying to use an assert to check if the total area of a polygon is more than 500 ha. But when I use data that is more than 500 it still passes the test.

```
    geom = feature['geometry']['coordinates']

    polygon = Polygon(list(chain(*geom)))
    print(polygon)
    geom_area = ops.transform(
        partial(
            pyproj.transform,
            pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:4326'),
            pyproj.Proj(
                proj='aea',
                lat_1=polygon.bounds[1],
                lat_2=polygon.bounds[3]
            )
        ),
        polygon)

    # Print the area in m^2
    print(geom_area.area)
    total_area = round(poly_area/10000, 1)
    print('total area hector:', round(geom_area.area/10000, 1))#rounded area to 1 dp in hectares

def test_area_max_500_ha():
    assert total_area < 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing `total_area` variable on `test_area_max_500_ha` function input data?

```
def test_area_max_500_ha(total_area):
    assert total_area < 500
```